# 'length' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, iis, null, timeout, updatepanel

Button click, executes method, sometimes takes a long (> 1 min time), populates a grid within an update panel. AsyncPostBackTimeout="600" set, should be plenty of time.

Do this locally and short and long duration works fine.

When deployed to IIS 7 short duration, don't experience any trouble at all.

However, the longer ones just give me the following error:

EDIT: Error on the browser javascript console

Message: 'length' is null or not an object
Line: 2
Char: 18021
Code: 0

EDIT: Currently deployed on a test server therefore below link will not work straight off the bat.

URI: http://epic/ScriptResource.axd?d=3tx7T6EWzEXOeemUaA1E9w3jSJacOpRDEfIjbEkIyJsG8AMEwHqtpEDV31v-r-fkISDFA9pg2hUPAVQOZf_hy7_e2FwgzwU07O7N-3j58tTVUJEKCPgxWMMo-sJpXo4c0&t=ffffffffbd2983fc

I really don't know where the length is coming from, the only other javascript I have is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function CancelClick() {
        alert('Changes have not been saved');
    }

    function StartProcedure() {

        document.getElementById("<%=lblExecute.ClientID%>").innerText = "Procedure currently executing";
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work. The error is coming from some compressed JavaScript, you can see that from the fact that the error is on character 18021. Load the debug version and you should get a better error message

Comment: Where does this error occur? In the browser's javascript console? In your server-side app?

Comment: Your error is not coming from the code you've shown so far.

Comment: The link does not work/show a different error.

Comment: Hello Juan - apologies for my ignorance, how do I go about loading the debug version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subject error was a red herring.

Stuck in an unhandled exception handler and before the above error, I was receiving another generic "Request time out"

I added `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="500"/>` to my web config and all my troubles disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a `"` at the end of `= "Procedure currently executing;`!

Comment: Just a typo/bad copy and paste